Optimizing Multi-Criteria Comparisons with Large DataFrames in Python
I’m working on a project involving sports performance analysis where I need to compare rows of a DataFrame based on multiple criteria (age, performance, and date). For each row, I need to compare it with all others and count those that meet certain conditions (less than or equal to for each criterion).
Context:

The DataFrame has tens of millions of rows.
I need to compare each row with others on multiple columns: age, performance, and date.
For each row, I want to count the number of successful comparisons.

Current Approach:
I am currently using Numpy and Pandas. However, when adding multiple criteria (age, performance, and date), the algorithm becomes too slow and doesn’t seem well-suited for multi-dimensional comparisons.
Here’s a simplified example of my current code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate random data
def generate_dynamic_dataframe(n):
    age = np.round(np.random.uniform(20, 50, n), 3)
    performance = np.round(np.random.uniform(5, 25, n), 2)
    dates = pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(946684800, 1672531199, n), unit='s')
    df = pd.DataFrame({'age': age, 'performance': performance, 'date': dates})
    return df

# Example comparison with NumPy vectorization (too slow for multiple criteria)
def compare_rows_with_vectorization(df):
    n = len(df)
    
    # Convert columns to NumPy arrays
    age_array = df['age'].to_numpy()
    performance_array = df['performance'].to_numpy()
    date_array = df['date'].astype('int64').to_numpy()  # Convert dates to int64
    
    # Create comparison matrices
    age_matrix = age_array[:, np.newaxis] <= age_array
    performance_matrix = performance_array[:, np.newaxis] <= performance_array
    date_matrix = date_array[:, np.newaxis] <= date_array
    
    # Combine comparisons
    valid_comparisons = age_matrix & performance_matrix & date_matrix

    # Count successful comparisons
    comparison_counts = valid_comparisons.sum(axis=1) - 1  # Exclude the row itself
    
    df['comparison_count'] = comparison_counts
    return df

# Generate data and apply the algorithm
df = generate_dynamic_dataframe(10000)
result_df = compare_rows_with_vectorization(df)

Problem:
This algorithm becomes too slow when processing DataFrames with millions of rows. It works, but the execution time is far too long. I’m looking for a more performant solution for this multi-criteria (age, performance, and date) comparison task.
For 10,000 lines, it already takes 5 seconds. And I have the impression that it believes exponentially.
Question:

Is there a more efficient method to perform multi-column comparisons (e.g., age, performance, and date) on a DataFrame with millions of rows?

Is it possible to use a Fenwick Tree or another efficient data structure for this multi-dimensional scenario

Are there better approaches using Pandas, NumPy, Dask, or even PySpark that could improve the performance?


Eventually I should apply this algorithm over several million lines, and the goal is to make this processing the fastest (a few seconds maximum).
Thanks in advance for your help! Any suggestions or optimization ideas are greatly appreciated.

If it weren't for the fact that you are finding rows that are less than the current row in multiple categories, you could use np.argsort() and that would be a much faster way of finding how many rows are less than the current row.

"it believes exponentially" AFAIK does not means anything in English, but I guess this is a bad translation (automated?) of the French sentence "ça croît exponentiellement" where the ^ is missing ;) . believe=croit while grows=croît. You should write "grows" or "increases" here.

Do you know the extents of the columns implicitly, or would you need to update them on-the-fly as well?

If the extents are known implicitly, you can use them to bin the results using np.histogramdd.  Then you only need to do the explicit calculations within the bin, and just add that to the sum of the lower bins.  A compiled tree structure would be faster, but that should improve your speed and allow some extensibility.

Is it actually useful to find comparisons where the first athlete is younger than the second athlete and the first athlete has lower performance than the second athlete and some arbitrary date is earlier than some other arbitrary date? If so, what does this actually mean? If not, what is the actual comparison you need to do?

using float32 isntead of float64 helps a bit. Other than that, I could not come up with any other idea than using multiprocessing. However, I am not sure it will help much because in Python there's this stupid serialization...
